# How to access to variable in outside the map function in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function test()
{
        $x = 10;
        $collection = collect([0, 10, 20]);

        $collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key){

            return $item + $x;
        });
}
```

I want to access the `$x` variable within the `map` function: how to do it?
When I try to get the value I got this error message:

> ErrorException: Undefined variable: x

Comment: Sorry my mistake `return ($item + $x);`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to make sure the [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) has access to the variable using the `use` keyword.

You would use it like this:

```
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($x) {

    return $item + $x;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function test()
{
    $x = 10;
    $collection = collect([0, 10, 20]);

    $collection = $collection->map(function ($item) use ($x) {
        return $item + $x;
    });
}
```

Please note that you had `return =` in your code which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public function test()
{
    $x = 10;
    $collection = collect([0, 10, 20]);
    $collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($x) {
       return $item + $x;
    });
}
```